# one signal sdk setup for sending push notification to a particular registered android or ios device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am very new to xamarin apps, can anyone please tell me how to setup one signal push notification for android and ios. I am able to achieve notification for all the registered device but i want to send notification to a particular registered device. How to achieve this in xamarin android and ios.

Comment: Show us what you already tried. What you searched for. What didn't worked.

Comment: as of now i am able to send notification based on one app signal id that notification is coming to all the devices which is having that app but i need to send notification only to particular registered mobile

Comment: Hi, Now you're registered your device without any unique Id, that's why while you're sending a push notification, it's sent to all registered devices. If you want to send particular device, you must be registered a device with specific unique id and while you send push notification you can use that unique id for sending specific device.

Comment: can you let me know how to achieve registering device with a unique id in xamarin forms app.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you want to attach the user data stored on your system by id or email to the device UUID acquired by OneSignal so that you can then target a user from your backend via the OneSignak API.

Xamarin has nothing to do for this, but sending the device UUID to your App backend while the user is logged in, and your App backend should store the UUID with the user data.

```
void SomeMethod() {
    OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);
}

private void IdsAvailable(string userID, string pushToken) {
    //here you can send the userID along with stored login token 
    //or any kind of id to your backend
}
```

for more info

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk